# How can I change, add, or delete a tag's attribute

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, attributes, tags

I have a html document with two types of 'tr' tags.

```
<tr bgcolor="lightgrey">
<tr>
```

Each tr tag has 3-4 lines of code with  tags within them. For some reason when trying to access the attributes I dont get 'lightgrey' as a result I either get an error or none. O am using beautiful soup to parse the html.

Here's the code I have tried:

```
list = soup.find_all('tr')
    for item in list:
        print(item.attrib) #continuously prints none
```

I tried accessing the attribute with

```
list = soup.find_all('tr')
        for item in list:
            print(item.find('tr')['bicolor'])
```

but i keep getting a "NoneType object has not attribute" or is not subscriptable

I want to be able to access the tag's attribute, read it, and to change the bicolor to a desirable color based on its original color.

Comment: can you share an url?

Answer (score 0):

See if it works this way:

```
my_list = soup.find_all("tr") #it's not a good idea to use a word like 'list' as a variable name...
for item in my_list:
   if len(item.attrs)>0: 
       print(item['bgcolor'])
```

Output:

> lightgrey